# Incrementing numbers using different worksheets from same workbook

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking to increment numbers using different worksheets (called `Ward 1`, `Ward 2`, `Ward 3`) etc.

> My current formula is:

```
  =Control!$G$2&"-"&Control!$H$2&LEFT(J4,1)&E4&RIGHT(Control!$B$6,1)&"00"&ROWS($1:1)
```

If I drag this down, it works and looks like: `PKW-APF1001, PKW-APF1002` etc.

Now, I need the formula to take the last active number from sheet `"ward 1"`, and start with the next number on sheet `"ward 2"`, and so on for the rest of the sheets

Lets say ward 1 has 13 active rows with data, last one would be `PKW-APF1013`, so for the next sheet `"ward 2"` I would like the following `PKW-APF2014` and if sheet `"ward 2"` has 10 rows with data, sheet `"ward 3"` should start with `PKW-APF3024`

Answer (score 0):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,('WARD 1'A:A<>"")*row(A:A),1)+1
```

That will determine the last row in column A on WARD 1 sheet without an error and then adds +1 to it to give you the starting number on the next sheet.  Use this add the above to your existing formula to get the lettering out front.

For subsequent row numbering, instead of building it from the ROW(), I would suggest you strip off the last X characters from the right side of the cell above and add 1 to it.